# Rails 3.1 routing all URL's point to one action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to have any URL that starts with `/capture` point to one action in my controller.  I have the following in my `routes.rb` file.

```
match '/capture'        => 'requests#index', via: :get, as: :requests
match '/capture/*other' => 'requests#index', via: :get
```

This works for me.  The `/capture` and `/capture/foo` (`foo` can be replaced with anything) URL's all point to the `requests#index` action.

Is there are more concise way to code this?

Answer (score 1):

you mean like this?

```
match "/capture*tail" => 'requests#index'
```

so everything after capture will be available in `params[:tail]`